# sql server, return resultset before sql timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

I have a query which times out due to the large size of the table (more than 10 million records).

Creating new indices is not an option. The query runs on sql server and is called by a .net website.

Is there any way I can return from the result before the timeout occurs.

```
select count(XYZ.A) from XYZ where XYZ.B = 'abc';
```

Something on the lines of measuring the time elapsed and returning the result just before query times out.

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Show us your table structure?

Comment: Do you have any indices on that tables? If you have an index on a small, non-nullable column (like an `INT` or `BIGINT`), then the `COUNT(*)` will use that column and quite possibly it will have to read **a lot less data pages** to determine the count

Comment: If we know what you want to do with all those records, we can do a better job helping you find a solution. For example, if the results don't really have that many rows, you're doing a table scan and a simple index change might make this query return instantly. If you do have a lot of rows, perhaps changing the order of the results (ie: omit order by entirely), or finding a better way to filter them down more would help.

Comment: Where do you call the query from? SSMS? .NET app? Elsewhere? Also try `select count(1)` instead of `select count(*)`

Comment: Its a legacy app, I dont want to mess with indices. The table just has approx 10 million rows. I am calling a stored proc from my .net app and the database is sql server.

Comment: Edit your question to include all that.  Also:  a .NET console app, a .NET website, or what?  << ---- that will affect the name of your config file.  And... are you asking how to speed up the query, or how to make your app wait longer and not timeout?

Comment: How long does SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM XYZ take?  How about SELECT TOP 100000 *?  Do those timeout as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding indexes to your table.

But then check your Execution Plan by going to Query > Display Estimated Execution Plan. Scroll down through the plan looking for the largest query cost. Click the green text. It'll probably says "Missing Index". Right click and choose Missing Index Details. It will generate generic code to create your indices. Edit the template and run it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding indexes is not an option.

Comment: Returning data while the query is still running is not an option. SQL does not estimate query time. It can estimate query cost, but this is not connected to run time. You'll have to find a work around, such as running the query in chucks (get all records for 2012, then '11, then '10, etc.) In my connection string I had to increase the default timeout for SSRS connections from 30 seconds to 600.